# How can I allow space in my preg_match pattern?

Tags: php, html

So far I tried to make pattern which allows alpha-numeric but not first number and only number. So far if I add space I still get an error like I used that pattern with name so what. If I can add space also between name will be amazing. Here is my pattern:

```
preg_match("/^(?!\d*$)[a-z\d]*$/i"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match("/^(?!\s\d*$)[a-z\s\d]*$/i");
```

`\s` means any kind of space.

Comment: Thanks a lot you are amazing